# Hmmm, seems like your kit isn't activating:Nativescript-fabric

Tags: ios, nativescript, crashlytics, google-fabric

I am using nativescript framework to build the mobile apps. I tried use the plugin nativescript-fabric.

But it won't work. I got the error like this  Fabric Crashlytics “Hmmm, seems like your kit isn't activating” whilst verifying install.(ios)

"Hmmm, seems like your kit isn't activating" message on the Fabric Controller after following the instruction to run the app in Xcode.

"nativescript-fabric": "^1.0.6",
  Crashlytics (3.9.3)
  Fabric (1.7.2)
Please give any suggestion. How to work with this. I need to upload the apk.

Comment: it may be useful to post your fabric crashlytics initialization code.

Comment: var nativescriptFabric= require("nativescript-fabric");
nativescriptFabric.Fabric.init();